Autorun with boot Raspberry Pi 4
I have such a problem
I wrote python script and want to run it automatically with boot through shell script.
I tried to add this .sh file to crontab -e in such way:
@reboot /home/path/to/my_script.sh
and in rc.local:
/home/path/to/my_script.sh &
My script:
conda activate /path/to/environment/bin/activate
python3 /home/path/to/main.py

In python file I made counter that write to UART:
import serial


ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200)
l = 1
while (1)
    print (l)
    ser.write(str(l).encode("utf-8"))
    l += 1

But nothing helped me to run this with boot.

You may have to search in your logs. About cron... What give which conda? (Are there in your regular  $PATH)?

Does the user have the rights to execute the script? Did you made the script executeble?
chmod +x /home/path/to/my_script.sh

If your script has the needed rights, there are five ways to run your script at startup:

rc.local
.bashrc
init.d
systemd
crontab

1. rc.local:
On your Pi, edit the file /etc/r.local and add commands to execute the python program.
python3 /home/path/to/main.py

2. .bashrc
If you want to run the script only for your user, you can add it to your .bashrc file found in your home directory.
simply add your python call at the end of the file.
3. init.d directory
Copy your script to the init.d directory
sudo cp /home/path/to/main.py /etc/init.d

Change to the init directory and edit your script. Add the lines needed by the init.d above your script:
# /etc/init.d/main.py
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          main.py
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

Run this command:
sudo update-rc.d main.py defaults

4. SYSTEMD
Create a Unit File
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/sample.service

Add the following text to the unit file
 [Unit]
 Description=My Sample Service
 After=multi-user.target

 [Service]
 Type=idle
 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/path/to/main.py

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target

The permission on the Unit file has to be changed to 644
sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/sample.service

5. crontab
As you did before, add the script with crontab -e
Resources:
dexterindustries

Yes, it's ok with permissions and it's executable. I can run it just type
./home/path/to/my_script.sh

Okay, I've solved this problem with adding my script to /etc/profile in such way:
/home/path/to/my_script.sh &

I don't know what's the problem with rc.local, but it works with profile

Warning : if you place this in /etc/profile, the script will be called every time a interactive login is done (including e.g. an ssh session is opened). It can lead to your script running multiple times at once
